# How can I recreate this color effect?

Tags: images, photoshop-effects

[image: Example of colour effect]

This color effect looks easy but I still can’t achieve this effect.

Comment: Hey ThuanNg, what have you tried?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/why-was-my-question-downvoted-and-or-closed)

Comment: i tried to use Multiply in blending but its just make the image darker and doesnt have the "soft overlay" like that.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/33690/how-to-colorize-an-image-as-in-the-example/33693#33693

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a gradient map in Photoshop.

`Image -> Adjustments -> Gradient Map`