# How can I change colors of a B&W graphic in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a black & white graphic, which I want to turn into a blue & yellow.

Black → blue,
white → yellow

I can do the first part by creating a solid color layer and change the blending options to "lighten", but then I have a blue & white image.

I have a vague idea that I should select highlights  and shadows, resp., and turn the selections into masks for a solid color layer, but I don't know how to do this. Also, I'm not sure this is the best route to go.

Photoshop is version CS6.

EDIT:

I think I found it, but I'm not completely satisfied yet.

In the "select" menu I select "color range" and then "shadows". I then add a mask using the selection. I make that layer yellow. Underneath I place a solid blue layer.

The problem is that the edges are very hard and jagged, like when you convert an 8-bit grayscale to an indexed color image. So the mask seems to consist of black and white only. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/33690/how-to-colorize-an-image-as-in-the-example/33693#33693

Answer (score 5):

The way I would do this is using a '*Gradient Map*' adjustment layer.

1. First make sure the *Adjustments* panel is visible. Go to '*Window → Adjustments*' and make sure '*Adjustments*' is checked.

[image: Window Menu]

2. Click 'Gradient Map' in the 'Adjustments' panel.

[image: Gradient Map]

3. Click the gradient in the pop-out(*Properties* panel), and edit. There will be default
   options, but you can click to edit any of them. Right hand side =
   black, left side = white.

[image: Gradient]

4. You can click on the layer in '*Layers*' to edit as you need. You can
   also edit how sharp of a drop off the gradient has... IE. where the
   parts between white/black become a combination of your new color
   combo. This isn't a hard re-color, but as it states a 'mapping' of a
   'gradient', so it might not be the exact result you were hoping for.
   Give it a shot.

[image: Layers Panel]

Final result:

[image: Final Result]

Comment: Then what?                         ................

Comment: Just updated-- apologies. I submitted it too early. Added a visual guide- let me know if that helps.

Comment: Good job. It's just a bit better to have the images in between the text so it's more clear which image goes with which step.