# How to make photos color like this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, overlay

i try to edit a photo like the picture.
i think that is an overlay color. after i try to make overlay with Photoshop, the result is totally diferent.

[image: Uptwon photo]

This is the result of my attempt

[image]

Comment: Similar question asked [How to colorize an image as in the example?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/33690/how-to-colorize-an-image-as-in-the-example/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy to do that and there are a lot of ways to do it, too.

- Create a new layer with a white radial gradient from center and set layer opacity to 60% (adjust according to your preferences).
- Add a HUE adjustment layer and set the saturation to -100.
- Add a photo filter adjustment layer, pick the color red and uncheck Preserve
  Luminosity and set the Density to 100%.

Look :

[image]

Comment: That was fast...but why (supposing that you did) did you downvote @voxwoman and @ryan? Their answers apply too. Like I said, there are a lot of ways to do this and mine is only one of them :)

Comment: You forget the density. haha. . . many thanks to u. :D

Comment: @cecep Yup, I forgot to mention to set it to 100% :)

Answer (score 0):

> i want to make effect like that photo, i thinks that just make a layer with red background and set opacity to 60% (overlay). i was do that, but the result is different.

Make a layer with the color you want on top of the original image, and set the **Blending Mode** to *Multiply* (see screencap below. The red part is a solid red layer with blending mode set to Multiply)

The Blending Mode dropdown is at the top of the layers panel.

[image]