# Blend people image into background!

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I found this awesome work designed by Kreativa Studio and I'm really curious about the effect of the woman picture. How to make an person image to blend into the background like this with photoshop.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to colorize an image as in the example?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/33690/how-to-colorize-an-image-as-in-the-example)

Comment: Do you mean the color or the frame?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve a look like this, but the fastest way seems to be to layer the 'person' on top of a colored background and put the **blend mode** on **'multiply'**. You wouldn't even need to cut out the person if the background is solid white.

You can find the blend mode dropdown above your layer panel, next to the opacity box.

[image: blend mode]

To learn more about blend modes I'd recommend reading this adobe guide: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/blending-modes.html