# Change the color of already painted brush strokes that are inside selection

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, brush, selections, brush-dynamics

How do I change brush-marks of a certain color (everything that is not white) into another color. For instance, having lasso-selected the following brush-marks, how do I change the color from black to red?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to colorize an image as in the example?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/33690/how-to-colorize-an-image-as-in-the-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the color  mode of the image to RGB. Insert 2 adjustment layers. On the top you should have layer Hue&Saturation, option colorize=ON to set the color. Below it you have layer "Curves" to lift the black to grey.

The colorization is disabled in the next image, the curves layer lifts black to grey:

[image]

The full effect:

[image]

Flatten the image or merge these 3 layers to fix the effect if needed.

There's no need to use adjustment layers. You can as well apply at first Image > Adjustments > Curves to change black to grey. Then apply Image > Adjustments > Hue&Saturation > Colorize to get the wanted color.

Making grey is a must, black and white cannot be colorized.

Another option is to invert your image to have white text on black and use it as a layer mask to solid red layer.

The third option is to make the black text to grey and insert to top a solid color layer with blending mode = Color

Methods 2 and 3 allow non-uniform coloring like this

[image]

Method 2 only allows other than white background. You must insert a new BG layer because layer mask makes the original BG transparent.

You can edit the layer mask onscreen if you Alt+Click the layer mask icon in the layers panel. This is needed for ex. to paste your text to the mask.